# Why I am getting blank input value?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Code :

```
var inputText = document.getElementById('input').value,
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    convertBtn = document.getElementById('convertBtn');

convertBtn.addEventListener('click',convert);

function convert(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    inputText = String(inputText);
    let binary = '';
    for(let n of inputText){
        binary += n.charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + ' ';
        console.log(binary)
      }

    output.innerText = binary;
    console.log(inputText)
}
```

Here, input value is not getting on 1st line..Its return blank on the console...
HTML code here:

```
<h2 class="text-center bg-secondary m-5 p-3 font-weight-bold1">Text To Binary</h2>
<form class="text-center m-5"></form>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Your Text :</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." id="input">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" id="convertBtn">Convert</button>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Binary :</span>
        </div>
        <h3 class="text-red" id="output"></h3>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please share the codesandbox

Comment: You are reading the value on page load, at which point the input is likely still blank. Get the value inside the `convert` function instead.

Comment: you need to read the value inside `function convert(event){` ... because `inputText = document.getElementById('input').value` doesn't change with every change to the input

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert(event){
    var inputText = document.getElementById('input').value; 
    event.preventDefault()
    inputText = String(inputText);
    let binary = '';
    for(let n of inputText){
        binary += n.charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + ' ';
        console.log(binary)
      }

    output.innerText = binary;
    console.log(inputText)
}
```